# Android native dialer not opening through java script in Web@Work Android

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, mobile

I am facing problem while opening the Android native dialer through JS. Using "tel:XXXXXXXXXX" to open a default dilaer and following is the code

```
HTML
<div class="phoneLinkDiv" onclick="javascript:openNativeDialer('tel:9291808586');" data-rel="external"></div>
JS
function openDialer(num) {  
    window.location.href = num; 
}
```

The above code working as expected in Chrome/Firefox but it is not working Web@Work enabled android device.

More Info:
I got to know that [ionicframework](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/making-phone-call-from-app-href-tel-123/1968/20) not allowing because of CORS. Is there anyway to enable CORS for particular web page through HTML or JS or any other ideas to open native dialer

Comment: Are you using webview for android??

Comment: No,Even in device also we are using chrome only but device enabled with Web@works which provides secure environment to access site.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `a` tag for redirection. eg `<a href="tel:555-999-8888">`